# PHP: Laravel Octane with Swoole Log Scraping

Tags: logging, swoole, laravel-octane

I'm currently trying to scrape the logs from my Laravel Octane application in a k8s cluster. The scraper gets the logs from the respective consoles, but due to the swoole (not openswoole) layer in front of the Laravel Octane I can't seem to get the Octane application logs, only the Swoole logs (error code, response size + time). The Laravel logs are stored in WORKDIR/storage/logs and the swoole config in the octane.php is set like this:

```
'swoole' => [
        'options' => [
            'package_max_length' => 256 * 1024 * 1024,
            'log_file' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        ],
    ],
```

Does anyone know how I can scrape the logs from the actual application? Is it even possible or does the application need to ship the logs actively to the logs instance?

The Swoole version is 5.0 and Laravel/Octane is 1.4.

Thanks in advance for any help!